# Why does sys.stdout.write("\b\b\b") erase only one character, if sys.stdout.write("\b\b") erases two, in a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to make my script write a percentage that updates, and I ran into the following problem: I need Python to erase the last bunch of characters I printed, but I can't get it to erase more than 2 characters.

Entering this in Jupyter Notebook

```
sys.stdout.write("abcd")
sys.stdout.write("\b")
```

outputs

```
abc
```

which is fine, let's erase one more

```
sys.stdout.write("abcd")
sys.stdout.write("\b\b")
```

outputs

```
ab
```

very well

```
sys.stdout.write("abcd")
sys.stdout.write("\b\b\b")
```

outputs

```
abc
```

what? What happened? why does it erase just one character instead of 3? What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: @rdas that's utterly obvious and counterintuitive at the same time, thanks. Is there no way I can erase 3 characters then?

Comment: @rdas wait, then why \b\b works? shouldn't the second \b erase the first one? Instead it correctly erases 2 characters!

Comment: The fact that this does not output `abcd` in both cases surprises me. What do you write to `sys.stdout` *after* the `\b`'s?

Comment: @mkrieger1 nothing, that is all I write

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please explain this unexpected \b (backspace) behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251434/please-explain-this-unexpected-b-backspace-behavior)

Comment: Do you type these commands in an interactive session, or are they in a script?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean, I'm using a Jupyter notebook

Comment: I mean, do you type `sys.stdout.write(...)` and then press Enter, and then the output appears, or do you write `sys.stdout.write(...)` to a file, save the file, and then run the file by clicking a "run" button or executing `python thefile.py` from the command line?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the former

Comment: In any case, as explained in the answers to the other question, `\b` does not *erase* anything, it only moves the cursor to the left, and what appears as output depends on what is written afterwards.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I don't think I'm having the same problem as in that question, for example sys.stdout.write("abcd")
sys.stdout.write("\b\b\b")
sys.stdout.write("fgh") outputs abcfgh, while as per that explanation I'd expect afgh

Comment: @mkrieger1 and if \b doesn't erase anything, but merely shifts the cursor to the previous character, then why do my first two example work? I'm very confused

Comment: I suspect that Jupyter Notebook writes something to `sys.stdout` by itself, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The "backspace" escape character '\b': unexpected behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792812/the-backspace-escape-character-b-unexpected-behavior)

Comment: @TomCarrick how does it explain that 3 backspace characters have the same effect as 1? (I'm not trying to sound as offensive as it reads, sorry)

Comment: @user2723984 I expect mkrieger1 is correct and it's an issue with how jupyter intercepts and manages its internal sys.stdout, because with a "raw" stdout using the normal python repl in a regular terminal `\b` behaves as expected (it just moves the cursor backwards at which point it's possible to overwrite the line content, and `"abcd\b\b\bfgh"` does indeed result in an output of `afgh`).